# Node edit page not showing up using page.tpl.php?

Tags: nodes, forms

I'm working on a new drupal 7 site right now (I'm new to drupal) and currently have given the ability to users to create nodes. The node creation page (url.com/node/add/) works just fine and uses the page.tpl.php template.

However, when I'm using the edit page (url.com/node/NODEID/edit/), it doesn't even load a page.tpl.php file. I went ahead and added some code to my page.tpl.php file to see if it would even read out--which it didn't. I've found that the edit page is inserting itself at the html.tpl.php level of the site. Is there a quick way I can get this to use page.tpl.php or by creating a node--edit.tpl.php or something? Hopefully I have made enough sense, but am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the setting 'Use the administration theme when editing or creating content' unchecked in you 'appearance' settings page. This would override your theme on the node edit pages causing your page.tpl.php file not to be used.